# Inconsistent results from spatial databases

Tags: postgis, oracle-spatial, sql-server-spatial, mysql-spatial

I'm trying to write something agnostic to whichever database vendor is chosen between MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, and PostgreSQL. However, I see inconsistent results in functions that return measures. In this instance, it's the Area/STArea/SDO_Area functions. I have a simple table with a geometry column, I've inserted the following Polygon in there:

POLYGON((20.0 20.0, 20.0 22.0, 22.0 22.0, 22.0 20.0, 20.0 20.0))

The SRID is 4326 and I've written 4 select statements, one for each database to retrieve the area.

**MySQL**

`SELECT ST_AREA(spatial_column) FROM spatial_table`

Returns: 46045765517.41474

**Oracle**

`SELECT SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA(spatial_column) FROM spatial_table`

Returns: 46045755446.0611

**SQL Server**

`SELECT spatial_column.STArea() FROM spatial_table`

Returns: 4

**PostgreSQL**

`SELECT ST_AREA(spatial_column) FROM spatial_table`

Returns: 4

I have all the relevant spatial indexes for each database, the bounding boxes, etc. In this instance which is right? And how do I make the ones that aren't, behave the same way? I've read competing information on whether this should be square meters or just a Cartesian area and I'm struggling to understand which it should be.

Comment: Very strange but in Postgres, using the second parameter to ST_Area (boolean use_spheroid=true) as either true or false gives me square meters. Take it away and it's back to 4.

Comment: Don't measure area in lat lon

Comment: The question here is what should be returned and how to make them the same. It’s not a conceptual question.

Comment: re https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Area.html see the differences between the two versions.

Comment: Yeah I see it now, it treats it as a geography with the second argument. So the following: "For geometry types a 2D Cartesian (planar) area is computed, with units specified by the SRID". That seems to make sense in that 4326 units would be decimal degrees, which makes me lean towards 4 as the right answer, which makes me think Oracle and MySQL are in fact wrong.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geom-sdo_area.htm#SPATL1110 appears to suggest that SDO_AREA should also return 4 as above for a geometry but it doesn't.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-polygon-property-functions.html#function_st-area also suggests the same but doesn't for 4326.

Comment: The SRID makes a difference. If you clobber the SDO srid with 0 instead of 8307, I'd expect you'd get a 4 from Oracle as well.

Comment: I'd assume 4 always with SRID 0 and meters for 4326 but it's inconsistent.